# Enumerate a list in jinja that satisfies a certain condition - with commas in between each item except for the last value printed

Tags: templates, jinja2

How do I omit the comma **only** on the last item in the returned list, here is my code below.

```
{%- for entity_id in states.group.all_updater_entities.attributes.entity_id -%}
  {%- if states(entity_id) == 'on' -%}
    {%- if not loop.last -%}
      {{ state_attr(entity_id, 'friendly_name') | replace ('Updater', '') }}{{', '}}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ state_attr(entity_id, 'friendly_name') | replace ('Updater', '') }}
    {%- endif -%} 
  {%- endif -%} 
{%- endfor -%} has updates available.
```

That `if not loop.last` condition doesn't work because the last item of the returned list might not be the list item of the group in the for loop. Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you modify your j2 like this (add condition if to the loop for):

```
{%- for entity_id in states.group.all_updater_entities.attributes.entity_id if states(entity_id) == 'on' -%}
    {%- if not loop.last -%}
      {{ state_attr(entity_id, 'friendly_name') | replace ('Updater', '') }}{{', '}}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ state_attr(entity_id, 'friendly_name') | replace ('Updater', '') }}
    {%- endif -%} 
{%- endfor -%} has updates available.
```

The advantage is that the special loop variable will count correctly; thus not counting the entities not iterated over.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you!  I'm new to jinja and templates in - can I ask what is the difference between {%- ... -%} and {% ... %}, what does the dash do?

Comment: its for controlling the block/whitespace...see https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-3-whitespace-control/

Comment: Thank you - very helpful. That is a great article.